# Combining two APIs into one array in PHP

Tags: php, api, dictionary

Looking to take the data from two API endpoints and merge them into one array using PHP.

While I'm aware of functions like array_merge, not actually looking to append the data, more like map it together at the end. Below is an example of what I'm looking to achieve.;

```php
$api1_endpoint = esc_url_raw( "http://api.com/endpoint" ); 
$api2_endpoint = esc_url_raw( "http://api.com/endpoint2" );

$api1 = json_decode( $api1_endpoint);
// {["sku"]=> string(12) "850661003403" ["productName"]=> string(16) "Product 1" ["productColor"]=> string(3) "red" }
$api2 = json_decode( $api2_endpoint);
// {["sku"]=> string(12) "850661003403" ["productName"]=> string(16) "Product 1" ["quantityAvailable"]=> float(5) }

$combined_apis = // function to combine $api1 and $api2 by ["sku"] or other key

foreach($combined_apis as $combined){
  echo $combined->sku;
  echo $combined->quantityAvailable;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more why in this case, array_merge is not suited for your problem?

Comment: In this case `array_merge` isn't suited because it appends one array to another. Looking to basically map the arrays together into one, rather than append.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function for that

```
public function combine_api_result($api1, $api2) {
    $output = $api1;
    foreach($api2 as $key => $value) {
        if ( ! isset($output[$key])) {
            $output[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```